# What should be my minimum/target sdk version for material design and external storage acess?

Tags: android

I want to write a very simple app that only has 2 requirements. Support for material design and uses the phone internal storage.

So when I created the Android studio project my minSdkVersion was set to 21 and my targetSdkVersion was set to 26.

This gave me the following problem. When I wanted to get access to internal storage I couldn't because of the new runtime permission system. I figured I needed to write the code for requesting persmissions but then I run into the problem that the requestPermissions function requires a minSdkVersion of 23.

So, here is what I want. I want to make sure that my app works in any android version higher than 5. What is the right way to solve this permission issue and what should my minSdk and targetSdk be?

I want to set my minSdkVersion to 21 and be done with it, but I don't know what problems that might bring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should request the permissions using the Support Library. The official documentation explains pretty well the entire process: [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).
As this guide says:

> using the support library is simpler, since your app doesn't need to check which version of Android it's running on before calling the methods

Comment: I've read the link. But I don't understand what you are saying. How is it that you don't need to check the app version?? Is  it because checking for permissions will be true with any sdk lower than 23?

Comment: If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.
That being said, you need to check permissions each time you need them. I think that in API lower than 22, checkSelfPermission method always return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED.

Comment: Luckily I have a 5.1.1 Tablet and a 7.0 Phone. And I can verify that checkSelfPermission returns the PERMISSION_GRANTED on lower APK. Sweet! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean haveStoragePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddPostActivity.this , new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And add this method at the beginning of`onCreate()` method and don't forget to add those two permission into mainifest file.

Comment: I don't think you need to chec for sdk int. It wlll never return a permission denied when it is lower than 23. But request permission needs to be with @TargeApi(23) annotations. So that already fores the check to be somewhere else.